# データベースに登録されているデータを配列にする

Tags: android, java, database, array

databaseデータベースに登録されているデータを配列にする方法を教えてください。

適当に作った配列は問題なく動作します。

```
String[] array = {"abc_1","abc_2","abc_3","abc_1","abc_5","abc_4"};
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
    .....array[i]....
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java
を参考に下を試しましたがデータは反映されません。

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cursor= database.rawQuery("select * from tbl_abc", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        abc_num = cursor.getString(4);
        list.add(abc_num);
    }

String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = list.get(i);
    .....array[i]....
}
```

対処法、お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

問題の切り分けのために、
以下のコードの直前に、`list.size()`をログ出力してはどうでしょうか?
この時点で`list`の要素が0件であれば、以降の操作が行なわれません。

```
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

また、`list`の要素に`"a", "b", "c"`と設定されている場合、上記のコードの結果、取得される`array`の内容も`"a", "b", "c"`となっているはずです。
そのため、for文の中で、再度、`array[i] = list.get(i)`する必要はありません。

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          array[i] = list.get(i);

            .....array[i]....
}
```

Comment: ログはとりあえず確認はしていましたが、なぜか同じログが30個以上連続して出てきていたので記載しませんでした。 記載部分以外の他の箇所に問題があるかも知れないので再度確認して再掲したいと思っています。 ありがとうございました。